# Wrong terminal emulator persists in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, debian, gnome-terminal, alacritty

I'm currently using Debian Buster (10): installed a new terminal emulator (Alacritty) along with a new shell (ZSH); and configured my system to use this new terminal & shell as the defaults.

Unfortunately, VScode continues--**regardless of the changes I make in my vscode settings file**--to use some sort of defunct terminal. Notice the screwed-up styling:

[screenshot of vscode with incorrect terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaJkH.png)

Anyone with knowledge on how to configure vscode to use the correct terminal would be very much appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a terminal font issue.

First you need to download and install a Powerline Font (there are quite a few, check this [link](https://medium.com/@elviocavalcante/5-steps-to-improve-your-terminal-appearance-on-mac-osx-f58b20058c84) for hints).

Then you need to assign that downloaded font to your terminal. You should add:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "<your powerline font>"
}
```

to your settings.json file, or search in the gui settings `Terminal integrated Font Family` and add it there.

I personally use [SauceCodepro NF](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/SourceCodePro/Regular/complete) which works great for me.